# Ajax post failed or something else

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to get a get post value after an AJAX call. First I will show you my AJAX codes:

```
$('#color').change(function(){

    var color = $('#color').find(':selected').text();
    var id = {$product_details.id};

    //alert({$product_details.id});
    //alert(color+id);

    var url = 'http://myurl';

    $.ajax({

        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: {'color='+color+'&id='+id},
        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    });

});
```

I have tested that I had posted to the correct url (not one above). I have tested the variables by alert. This is my PHP file:

```
echo $_POST['color'];

if(isset( $_POST['color'] )){
    echo 'hi';
    //get_unit();
}
```

But I am unable to echo the $_POST['color']. What could be the problem?

Comment: `data: {'color':color, 'id':id},` try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO need `{}` when you pass post data in query string, `{}` will be used when you send data in object, please try this way

```
data: 'color='+color+'&id='+id
```

// OR

```
 data : {"color" : color, 'id' : id}
```

//

```
<script>
    $('#color').change(function(){

        var color = $('#color').find(':selected').text();
        var id = {$product_details.id};

        //alert({$product_details.id});
        //alert(color+id);

        var url = 'http://myurl';

        $.ajax({

            url: url,
            type: 'post',
            data: 'color='+color+'&id='+id,
            // OR
            // data : {"color" : color, 'id' : id}
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change:

```
data: {'color='+color+'&id='+id},
```

to:

```
data: {'color':color, 'id':id}
```

since you've used `POST` method.

Comment: why change 'post' to 'POST'?

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I had tried this method before my posted question above and somehow my page would not even load.

Comment: Would capital and lower case post matter?

Comment: @Jian Short, no, and because of that i ask Felix why he suggest to use 'POST' instead 'post'.

Comment: @Alexander I'm not sure it's case-sensitive or not, since the default type of AJAX from jQuery docs are `POST` or `GET`

Comment: @Felix, `type` in `jQuery.ajax` is not case-sensitive.

Comment: @Alexander Ok, I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

```
          $.ajax({
            url:Url,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'color': color1 ,'Id':id1  }),
            success: function (msg) {
             alert(msg);
                }
```

Try to use this format.color1 and id1 are local variable that you stored your data on them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with two changes:

change this:

```
var id = {$product_details.id};
```

to this:

```
var id = $product_details.id;
```

because you have a wrong syntax of an object this should either be with `{key:value}` pairs or you should do the change as above.

and you should post your data this way:

```
data: {'color':color, 'id':id},
```

Comment: It's not this lol because I'm using Smarty and it just displays the value and it is not a key value pair thing.

Comment: well you should have attached the tag smarty and about it then, nonetheless you got it working welcome to stackoverflow.